# ASPX update Panel with Custom Table Code not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, updatepanel

I have a webpage in which i am attempting to use an update panel to show some database information. I have the code working correctly, but the page refreshes when either the Results per Page is changed or the Sort By is changed. So i tried to set the code up to be asynchronous by adding the triggers etc, but for some reason when i do this the table doesn't update at all. The update panels progress is triggered and 'Loading' appears, but the data itself doesn't change at all. Basically, in order to change the data, i update the Datasource in which the code is using by using DataSource1.SelectCommand "SELECT * FROM .... WHERE ...".

- The datasource returns results correctly as i have tested this.
- The update panel is refreshing as the progress event triggers
- The HTML which is returned to the main page is correct as i run this function to start with and the table is populated, it just doesnt work when trying to update.

Here is the original code which works with a refresh :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-4 columns" style="padding-top: 25px;">
</div>
<div class="large-3 large-offset-1 columns">
<label for="results">
Results Per Page :
</label>
<asp:DropDownList name="results" ID="results" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
OnTextChanged="results_TextChanged">
<asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>100</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="large-4 columns">
<label for="filter">
Sort By :</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="filter" name="filter" runat="server" OnTextChanged="filter_TextChanged"
AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:ListItem>Name A to Z</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Name Z to A</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Age Youngest to Oldest</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Age Oldest to Youngest</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Location A to Z</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Location Z to A</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Last Logged In</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</div>
<asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
<ProgressTemplate>
Loading
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<table class="large-12 columns">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 40%;" />
<col style="width: 15%;" />
<col style="width: 15%;" />
<col style="width: 15%;" />
<col style="width: 15%;" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;">
<th class="aupairColour">
Photo
</th>
<th class="aupairColour">
Name
</th>
<th class="aupairColour">
From
</th>
<th class="aupairColour">
Age
</th>
<th class="aupairColour">
Last Logged In
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<%= LoopBlock()%>
</tbody>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here is the Behind Code :

```
protected string LoopBlock()
{
//update datasource (the actual code for this has more switches etc)
if (filter == "Name A to Z")
{
DataSource1.SelectCommand "SELECT * FROM .... WHERE ...".
}
else
{
DataSource1.SelectCommand "SELECT * FROM .... WHERE ...".
}

//items per page value
int ipp = Convert.ToInt32(results.Text);

//get the HTML to print out to the screen, pass the Items per Page to this function
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = LoopBlockCode(ipp);

//return the HTML to the place in which it was called on the main page
return Convert.ToString(sb);
}

private System.Text.StringBuilder LoopBlockCode(int ipp)
{
//create a data view so the items can be dealt with
DataView dv = (DataView)Aupairs_DataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
DataRowView drv;
//create a string builder so that long strings of HTML can be built
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
int n = Convert.ToInt32(ipp);
string name, city, country;
int age, numList;
//gets the amount of items returned from the DB query in another function
if (totalCount < ipp)
{
numList = totalCount;
}
else
{
numList = ipp;
}
try
{
for (int i = 0; i < numList; i++)
{
//loop each item that was returned from the DB and add it to the HTML elements
drv = dv[i];
//get age from DOB using the function in script
age = GlobalScript.AgeFromDOB(Convert.ToDateTime(drv["dob"].ToString()));
if (age >= Convert.ToInt32(min) && age <= Convert.ToInt32(max))
{
sb.Append("<tr>");
sb.Append("<td>");
sb.Append("<img height='100' width='100' src='" + drv["photo"].ToString() + "' alt='Family Profile Picture' />");
sb.Append("</td>");
sb.Append("<td>");
//capitalise the first letter of the name using function in script
name = GlobalScript.FirstLetterToUpper(drv["first_name"].ToString(), true);
//
sb.Append(name);
sb.Append("</td>");
sb.Append("<td>");
//capitalise the city and country  using function in script
city = GlobalScript.FirstLetterToUpper(drv["city"].ToString(), true);
country = GlobalScript.FirstLetterToUpper(drv["country_desc"].ToString(), true);
//
sb.Append(city + ", " + country);
sb.Append("</td>");
sb.Append("<td>");
sb.Append(age);
sb.Append("</td>");
sb.Append("<td>");
sb.Append(drv["last_logon"].ToString());
sb.Append("</td>");
sb.Append("<tr>");
sb.Append("<tr style='border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;'>");
sb.Append("<td colspan='4'>");
sb.Append("<p>Description</p>");
sb.Append("<p>" + drv["intro_heading"].ToString() + "</p>");
sb.Append("<p>Interests</p>");
sb.Append("<p>" + drv["interests"].ToString() + "</p>");
//conversion of dates for start and finish
sb.Append("<span class='label'>Looking for a Family from " + Convert.ToDateTime(drv["start_date"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " to " + Convert.ToDateTime(drv["end_date"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " for " + drv["shortest_term"].ToString() + " to " + drv["longest_term"].ToString() + " months.</span>");
sb.Append("</td>");
sb.Append("</tr>");
}
}
return sb;
}
catch
{
sb.Clear();
sb.Append("");
return sb;
}
}

protected void results_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
UpdatePanel1.Update();
}

protected void filter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

And to try and get the async working i have used :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(results);
ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(filter);
}
```

I tried to add the  code in the HTML to add the triggers for the update panel, but this didnt seem to work and i had read that doing the registering of triggers was better in the behind codes load event?

I actually have other filter controls outside of the update panel that i am using the above RegisterAsyncPostBackControl for, but i thought i would simplify things by cutting those out for now and just try to get these control working.